# How to use the method getOrCreate of SparkContext class in spark-core version 1.6.0?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am using the *SparkContext* class in *spark-core* library version 1.6.0. There is no *getOrCreate* method in the class. But it was in *1.5.0* version. How can I still use the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the method of `SQLContext` not of `SparkContext` and is still available in 1.6.0 version.

```
getOrCreate(SparkContext sparkContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in the SparkContext 1.6:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#getOrCreate()

It's not in the JavaSparkContext. I was confused initially as well.

Comment: Calling this function returns a 'not a member' error now.